# Do accesses in a constructor to a shared static variable need to be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, synchronization, static-members

I know that constructors cannot be synchronized in Java.  Does this mean that if a constructor modifies a static variable within the class, and if constructors could be invoked from multiple threads, that the access needs to be synchronized, as shown?

```
public class MyClass {
  private static int count = 0;

  public MyClass() {
    synchronized(MyClass.class) {
      count++;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that static, mutable variables are a code smell, right?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I had not realized they were considered a smell, but I do now.  Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/wiki/WhySingletonsAreControversial) is a citation that might explain _why_ they're a code smell.  It focuses on singletons -- which are a particular example of static state -- but the concerns apply more generally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely - after all, it's accessing a shared resource, potentially via many threads. I would personally just use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead.

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

  public MyClass() {
    count.incrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

Note that we can now make the variable final as that *variable* doesn't change value, and we don't need to synchronize any more as the whole point of the classes in [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) is that they can be used atomically without extra synchronization.

Even if you *are* in the situation where you need to synchronize, I wouldn't use `MyClass.class` to do so - that's a reference which other code might decide to synchronize on, so you can't really reason about your code any more. I would write (again, only if `AtomicInteger` wasn't good enough for some reason):

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final Object countLock = new Object();
  private static int count = 0;

  public MyClass() {
    synchronized(countLock) {
      count++;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

(In this case you'd also want to synchronize on `countLock` anywhere else you access `count`, even just for reading.)

Comment: Presumably `count` is being maintained for use elsewhere. In the second example, you'd also want to synchronize on `countLock` for any read accesses to `count`.

Comment: @TedHopp In that situation it would probably be better to make count volatile and avoid synchronizing on the read case (of course, still synchronizing on the increment case).

Comment: @increment1 - Declaring it volatile would still allow the variable to be read while it was in the middle of being updated. This would not mess up the update (the way unsynchronized updates could), but would mean that the value returned would be determined by a race condition.

Comment: @TedHopp Outside of additional external synchronization, two independent threads accessing this class are already subject to a race condition (does the update happen before or after the other thread's read).  Simply synchronizing on the read of the count does not address the situations where a race condition would have an impact on this code, so I would argue that volatile is equally deterministic in this case.  If there is an example that shows this to be untrue then I am interested to see it because I cannot think of one.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm questioning whether the second code example is really safe. Since `count` isn't volatile, couldn't different threads have different copies?

Comment: @espertus: Not if you always synchronize on `countLock` whenever you access the variable. Only one thread will ever be in such a synchronized block at once, and the memory model ensures that a write never moves to "after" the end of the block, and a read never moves to "before" the start of the block

Answer (score 1):

Some sort of synchronization is necessary and that would work, yes.  It would accomplish the same thing as a synchronized static method.  You might consider using an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, I'd recommend using an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: I feel the need to coin the term: "To be Skeeted!"

Comment: @Gray - indeed. But one must give credit where credit is due. That was a nice answer.

Comment: Sure thing.  That's why he's John Skeet.

Comment: @Gray - Well, I'd reverse cause and effect, but I agree. :)